# How to debug a Discord bot while an older version is still running?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have developed my own simple discord bot (with discord.js) and deployed it to a node server.
Everything is running fine.

Now I want to add some more features to it. During development I'd like to test it locally (of course).

Question is: Can I run my bot locally and test it without disrupting my currently running bot?

If not:
Do I need another bot/token instance?
How can I test my bot without disrupting my currently running bot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, when you use the **same** token for your local bot and for your bot, that is hosted on your node server, **it has a total of 2 instances**.

- **Bot on Node server** = 1 instance of the bot
- **Bot on local server** = 1 instance of the bot

Which makes a total of 2 instances of the same bot, what you don't want, because then, whenever you execute a command, where the bot is on, it executes the command **twice**.

Therefore, if I were you, I would create **another bot application** [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/) and use this new bot to test the bot's new features locally.

**99%** of all bot developers do it like this, because they don't interrupt the main bot with this method.

Comment: Makes you wonder how many "dev bots" are out there on Discord. I was hoping there was some sort of tool developed by Discord to let us use the same token for testing and production, but I guess that's not the case (yet?).